# Live audio stream playback with a delay

Tags: audio, network-programming, buffer

This might be a broad question. I'll try my best to keep the scope as narrow as possible.

I have the url of a mp3 stream I want to playback the stream with an adjustable delay.
So the final program will have some input to allow the user to specify the exact delay. Right now I don't have a particular language or library in mind specifically, cross-platform would be ideal.

---

For the implementation I have the following:

A ring buffer to hold the audio data and the following pointers:

`loadPtr := where to store next byte`

`livePtr := loadPtr + 1, first byte ready from streaming`

`delayedPtr := livePtr + delta, where delta is a delay (default=0)`

TCP connection for getting the data.

---

I've tried searching, but have not had much luck. Specially,

1. how do I store the continuous stream from TCP connection into the ring buffer?
2. what do I use to play audio from a memory buffer?
3. would the structure of the mp3 file, headers and data sections, affect this buffer structure?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @RonyTesler It's been a long time since I asked this, but no I didn't end up solving it. If you find a solution please post here, I'll be happy to accept it as the answer and give you an upvote. But if it'll help you I can maybe provide some areas you can research which might be helpful:

Comment: (1) youtube.com/watch?v=uiW1D1Vc7IQ This shows you how to playout a sine way in C (video shows Windows version, but I've done it using the cross platform SDL library using `SDL_QueueAudio` by just replacing the relevant function implementations with SDL calls). You can message me if you want snippet of the relevant code, I can't release the entire code base publicly. You can do something like this and add a delay using whatever code you can think of. Of course SDL has binding in other languages if C/C++ aren't what you prefer

Comment: (2) There is also OpenAL. Haven't used it myself, and I don't know if it'll give you what you're looking for, but I think it might. It probably has a higher leaving curve than SDL